# Legendre Transformation

Tags: thermodynamics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, mathematics

Can someone explain how the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) for multivariable functions work? I have been trying to find Legendre transformation for a function like $$F(x, y) = x^{2}+y^{2}+xy.$$ But I don't know how to approach it. And also does Legendre transform in multivariable functions have any physical significance like Fourier transforms.

Comment: Sure they have a meaning, but this is a separate question. Your main one belongs to [math.se].

Comment: Without any context in physics, this appears to be a question about Mathematics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - there are a number of definitions of the Legendre transformation, but the one used most commonly in physics is as follows:

For each variable of your function (i.e. $x$ and $y$ for you) we define a "conjugate variable" (often called a "conjugate momentum"). Let's call these $\{p, q, \ldots\}$ (i.e you need $p$ and $q$ that are conjugate to $x$ and $y$). These variables are defined by $p = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\,\, q = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\,\, \ldots$, so are simple partial derivatives of your original function.

Then we construct a new function, the Legendre transformation, 
$$F^{\star}(p, q, \ldots) = px + qy + \ldots - F(x, y, \ldots) \bigg|_{p = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\,\, q = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\,\, \ldots}$$
What does the notation with the vertical line mean? Well you have a set of $N$ equations relating the $N$ conjugate variables to the $N$ original variables and you must solve this system of equations to express $x$, $y$, $\ldots$ in terms of the conjugate variables $p$, $q$ etc. That means that at the end of your calculation you will have a function of two variables $p$ and $q$ because you will have eliminated $x$ and $y$ in favour of the conjugate variables.

Here are the steps you must complete:

1. $p = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = $?
2. $q = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = $?
3. Invert these equations to write $x = x(p, q)$ and $y = y(p, q)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.
4. Form $F^{\star}(p,q) = p x(p, q) + q y(p, q)  - F\big(x(p, q), y(p, q)\big)$. Then $F^{\star}$ is your Legendre transform.

Two other interpretations of the Legendre transform are (restrict to one variable for simplicity)

1. The derivative of the Legendre transform $F^{\star \prime}(p)$ is the inverse function of the derivative of the original function: $F^{\star \prime} = F^{\prime \, -1}$
2. For convex functions the Legendre transform is the function that maximises $px - F(x)$ over x: $F^{\star}(p) = \max_{x} \{ px - F(x) \}$. You can see how this leads to the (implicit) equation $F^{\prime}(x) = p$.

As for applications in physics....

1. In quantum mechanics / quantum field theory, the conjugate momentum to a variable in a Lagrangian, $\mathcal{L}(\phi, \dot{\phi})$ is defined to be $\pi = \frac{\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}$. One goes to the Hamiltonian description of the problem by taking the Legendre transformation:
   $$\mathcal{H}(\phi, \pi) = \pi \dot{\phi} - \mathcal{L}(\phi, \dot{\phi}) \big|_{\pi = \frac{\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}}$$ that eliminates $\dot{\phi}$ from the problem.
2. In thermodynamics, starting from the internal energy (say), $U(S, V)$, we can get the Helmholtz free energy as (negative!) the Legendre transform with respect to entropy, $S$. Now since $dU = T dS - p dV$, it is clear that the conjugate variable (don't confuse $p$ with the pressure here) to $S$ is $p = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} = T$ and so negative the Laplace transform would be 
   $$F(T, V) = -\left[p S - U(S, V) \right] = -\left[ T S - U(S, V) \right] = U - TS$$
   with the requirement that, for any particular gas, we express its entropy, $S$, in terms of temperature and volume, $V$, so that $F$ becomes a function of $T$ and $V$ (this is easy once we have an explicit expression for $U(S, V)$).

Comment: Great answer. I would add that strictly speaking, the Legendre transform is only defined for concave-definite functions, because only then is the partial derivative invertible. Sometimes there are ways around this requirement though, when there's a "natural" inverse branch.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80715/discussion-on-answer-by-lux-legendre-transformation).

Comment: This is somewhat frustrating for both author and writer since, according to SE guidelines, the answer was set up for the op to solve - and then check their answer - comments are a perfect place to achieve this, and would moreover provide a roadmap for future visitors to see how to arrive at the answer. Don't appreciate a full conversation being moved without prior warning or checking with those who actually took part in it. (Nevermind I don't know how to access "chat")

Comment: @lux comments will sometimes disappear, but they will stay in chat forever.

Comment: I appreciate that and understand the tag "comments not for extended discussion." At the risk of raising a philosophical point my argument above, put more bluntly, is that the comments in question (whether they be classed as discussion or not) were as pedagogical (if not more) as the answer, and as such I would have preferred that they stay in place for future users.

Comment: @lux You can continue that discussion in chat by simply clicking the link in ACuriousMind's comment. No additional sign-ups, and you already have the rep needed for chat. It's intuitive once you get there. It's also a good idea to leave one comment here saying "The discussion in chat is about so-and-so" for future readers, although I don't think that's absolutely necessary here. Other people can easily click the link ACM posted to see the conversation if they want to; it's not being deleted and it's _definitely_ not being stopped when a mod moves it to chat.